# How can I start playing a music with AvFoundation at chosen currentTime of the music?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I just want to play my music at 55sec currentTime of the music. I mean, I don't want to play it from the begging, but from 55sec time.

I am stuck, because I just wanted to set the currentTime to 55sec, but it tells me that currentTime is a "get-only property"

Thanks a lot by advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134109/seek-to-a-certain-position-in-avplayer-right-after-the-asset-was-loaded

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `AVPlayer` to do that? If you are, I think you probably can use the function `AVPlayer.seek(_ time: CMTime)` to do that job, here is the code that I am using in my project:

```
let time = CMTime(seconds: 55, preferredTimescale: 1)
self.player?.seek(to: time)
```

hopefully that helps :-)

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot for your help, I ll try to do that and come back to you ;) Thanks a lot !